# How to play audio on a loop using NAudio library?

Tags: c#, .net, audio, naudio

I wrote some code that sets new playlist each time at fixed intervals and then plays it, but after the first play, it doesn't play anymore. I still get 55 printed in the console, so my code is running, it's just the player stops working.

```cs
if (AlarmSystem.OutputDevice.PlaybackState != PlaybackState.Playing)
{
  var playlist = new ConcatenatingSampleProvider(AlarmSystem.GetTriggeredAlarmsPlaylist());
  AlarmSystem.OutputDevice.Init(playlist);
  AlarmSystem.OutputDevice.Play();

  Console.WriteLine(55);
}
```

I checked the audio playback also seems to be interrupted even though I am checking for PlaybackState and only run the above code if it's not PlaybackState.Playing.

I tried calling Dispose before also and even recreating OutputDevice but it doesn't play again.

In my code I am getting the new playlist so I can play that one after the old one finishes.

Comment: Is the above code wrapped in some other kind of structure ( for or while loop)?

Comment: @fdcpp: No it's called from a BackgroundWorker at fixed intervals.

Comment: Put code into a USING block where the objects inside the block will get disposed after leaving the block